# How to split a data into k-folds NOT randomly in matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, cross-validation

I have a dataset, for simplicity let's say it has 1000 samples (each is a vector).

I want to split my data for cross validation, for train and test, **NOT randomly**<sup>1</sup>, so for example if I want 4-fold cross validation, I should get:

**fold1**: train = 1:250; test= 251:1000

**fold2**: train = 251:500, test = [1:250 ; 501:1000]

**fold3**: train = 501:750, test = [1:500; 751:1000]

**fold4**: train = 751:1000, test = 1:750

I am aware of [CVPARTITION](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html), but AFAIK - it splits the data randomly - which is not what I need.

I guess I can write the code for it, but I figured there is probably a function I could use.

---

(1) The data is already shuffled and I need to be able to easily reproduce the experiments.

Comment: I assume you are aware of this, but if the only goal is exactly reproducible work, I would recommend setting `rng` to initialize your random generator before randomizing the sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that does it in general:

```
function [test, train] = kfolds(data, k)

  n = size(data,1);

  test{k,1} = [];
  train{k,1} = [];

  chunk = floor(n/k);

  test{1} = data(1:chunk,:);
  train{1} = data(chunk+1:end,:);

  for f = 2:k
      test{f} = data((f-1)*chunk+1:(f)*chunk,:);
      train{f} = [data(1:(f-1)*chunk,:); data(f*chunk+1:end, :)];
  end
end
```

It's not an elegant 1 liner, but it's fairly robust, doesn't need `k` to be a factor of your number of samples, works on a 2D matrix and outputs the actual sets rather than indices.

Comment: Seemed to have worked for me. I am not a matlab expert, care to elaborate why you did not include the first iteration in the for loop?

Comment: It was just less thinking not to, because the `train` set is always disjoint except the first time. Hmmm although I guess not the last time either :/ If you can edit it to be in the loop then please do :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `k*n` smaples you want to divide to `k` folds with `n` samples in train and `(k-1)*n` in test (in your question `k = 4`, `n = 250`).
Then

```
 >> foldId = kron( 1:k, ones(1,n) );
```

`foldId` gives you the index of the training fold each sample belongs to.

For fold `f` you can get the indices of training and test samples using

```
 >> trainIdx = find( foldId == f );
 >> testIdx  = find( foldId ~= f );
```

(You can use logical indexing instead of the `find` and speed things up a bit).

Answer (score 1):

To divide the dataset into `k` folds of length `n` you can use:

```
f=arrayfun(@(x)struct('train',x*n+(1:n),'test',setdiff(1:n*k,x*n+(1:n))), 0:k-1);
```

where `f` is a structure array with fields `train` and `test` containing the indices for corresponding fold. 
For example for `n=5` and `k=3` and fold `2`:

```
>> f(2).train
ans =
     6     7     8     9    10
>> f(2).test
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5    11    12    13    14    15
```

You can even extract data directly. Let's say your data is a 2D matrix of `n*k` rows

```
E=arrayfun(...
@(x) struct('train', D(x*n+(1:n),:), ...
            'test',  D(setdiff(1:n*k, x*n+(1:n)),:)), 0:k-1)
```

Say your data is

```
D = [(1:15).^2; (1:15).^3].';
```

For fold `2`, `E` contains:

```
>> E(2).train
ans =
          36         216
          49         343
          64         512
          81         729
         100        1000
>> E(2).test
ans =
           1           1
           4           8
           9          27
          16          64
          25         125
         121        1331
         144        1728
         169        2197
         196        2744
         225        3375
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Matlab 2023, you can now use a custom cvpartition. For example, from the Matlab documentation:

c = cvpartition("CustomPartition",[1 2 2 1 3 3 1 2 3 2]) indicates a 3-fold cross-validation scheme, with the first, fourth, and seventh observations in the first test set.

c = cvpartition("CustomPartition",[true false true false false]) indicates a holdout validation scheme, with the first and third observations in the test set.

You can generate the vector of numbers using `kron( 1:k, ones(1,n) )` as shown in the answer by Shai, where k is the number of folds and n the number of samples in each fold.

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html